# Lua Declaring a function to be false

Tags: lua

How do you name an entire function false in Lua based on conditions?
example:

```
if homeruns == 1 or homeruns == 2
then function BabeRuth() = false
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "an entire function false"?

Comment: Perchance, do you come from a [Functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) background?

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing here, but perhaps you want this:

```
function BabeRuth()
  if homeruns == 1 or homeruns == 2 then
    return false
  else 
    return true
  end
end
```

which can be written more succinctly as

```
function BabeRuth()
  return not (homeruns == 1 or homeruns == 2)
end
```

Continuing my guessing game, perhaps you want this, instead of relying on global variables:

```
function BabeRuth(homeruns)
  return not (homeruns == 1 or homeruns == 2)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is this:

```
function_name = nil
```

You don't want `function_name()` since that *calls* the function.

But I'm not 100% sure I know what you're doing. Are you trying to remove a function (say in a sandboxing context for security?)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redefine the function `BabeRuth` to return false upon invocation (from then on) after a condition is met, you can bind it to a new anonymous function like so:

```
> homeruns = 1
> if homeruns == 1 then BabeRuth = function() return false end end
> BabeRuth()
false
```

the main part being

`BabeRuth = function() return false end`